# txt file with ascii tables in Lyx

Tags: lyx, text, ascii

I have  txt file with some ascii characters (report from a software simulation) and i want to copy it in Lyx but the result is awfull. For example in txt file i have the following. table:

[image]

I want to copy it in Lyx, but not as a pic, as text!! Is it possible ?

Comment: Search the forum for **verbatim text.**

Comment: well cant find something similar to my issue..

Answer (score 1):

If you already have it as an external file the easiest method is probably to do  Insert --> File --> Child document, select the file in question, and set the "Include type" to *Verbatim*.

Comment: Did that but i get a lot of errors when compilling it .. nothing happens !

Comment: @ALdaperan Which errors exactly?

Comment: @ALdaperan I think this is the correct general answer. Since you asked a general question without any specific example file, I would suggest accepting this answer and starting a new question where you include a LyX minimal example file and a minimal example file that is included (in the way suggested in this answer) that still produces the error you see. Please also specify the error. Remember, make the examples as simple as possible. For more information on a minimal example, see here: https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample. In your next question, feel free to link to this question.